# sms mobile nokia using computer, only status unread

Tags: windows-xp, sms, hyperterminal

reading sms from mobile phone nokia, have two methods read all or read only one.

but how to

reading only sms with status "rec unread"

using hyper terminal windows xp

Comment: "using computer" - can you be more specific? What protocol? What language? What have you tried so far? (Are you even asking how to write a program to do this, or is this "how to do it in Program X"?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using an AT command interface?

The standard AT+CMGL (list all messages) command can be given a parameter with the status, 0 is REC UNREAD so
AT+CMGL=0 
should give you only REC UNREAD messages.

Note that listing or reading a REC UNREAD message causes it to become REC READ.